# MySQL Multiple Tables or Massive Table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Designing up a database for weather stations. I'm not sure which would be the right way to lay out the database. I've got down to these two solutions and here are the constraints.

1. Each station has its data uploaded every 10 seconds (Temp, Humid & Time).
2. Has to support hundreds, possibly thousands of individual stations.

So is it best to create a new table for each station to write to seeing as many rows will be constantly written, or create one monster table adding in the station ID to know where it originated?

[image: Database Ideas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, go with the second model, but if you always need to pull down all of the objects at a single station, go with the first model.

The rationale is that if you need to always get all the weather data of a single station, you have to have the database server scroll through the entire aggregate table of all the stations.  The runtime would increase as the number of stations increased.

Comment: Yeah and there is where my problem is, I'll be accessing the data in several ways. Total rows from each station for graphing, latest from each station etc. I thought spreading the data across several tables would be better than a gigantic records table. I understand the performance will slow regardless of which design, it's just a matter of which is better, more stable etc.

Comment: Is this a relational database or a structured nosql?

Comment: Assuming it's a relational database and the data collection is going to run for a long period (years) at each station, I would actually go with the first model.  It's a lot easier to manage the data of each station by breaking it into multiple tables.  Also, you get the added benefit of not having to set search conditions (e.g. WHERE STATION_ID=X), which will slightly help reduce latency between the two models.

Comment: I was thinking relational, as MySQL is what I know. Should I be looking at nosql then?

Comment: Thanks Michael I think I will go with the first option too, it seems to make more sense at this point in time.

Comment: Yeah, I've worked with big data in biology and to setup a scaleable system for a lot of meteorological data, you should really use a nosql or some non-relational database that can handle the throughput.  MongoDB is a very popular option for big data that have somewhat analogous query commands, but I've personally never tried it myself. http://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-overview

Comment: @Sam Glad I could help.  If you like the answer, upvote.

Comment: I would if I had the rep ;)

Answer (score 0):

The second one makes more sense and is more common. Making a table for each individual station is silly, and takes away the entire point of using SQL. SQL is designed for "massive tables" like the one you want to have and thus you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: When talking massive, can MySQL easily handle 360,000 new rows per hour?

Answer (score 0):

The second choice is the right way.

The first diagram would be a huge overload data for the database.

Also in the stations table you should include the StationID as a foreign key.

Then by linking the foreign key of the Stations table to the primary key of StationData table you can access all of the data using an innerjoin.

Hope this helps you out!